What is the effect of wrapping a manual assignment of weights to a PyTorch layer with a `torch.no_grad()` context manager?
I'm trying to create a linear layer in PyTorch and then manually set the weights of the linear layer like this:
import torch
layer = torch.nn.Linear(10, 10)
layer.weight = torch.nn.Parameter(torch.ones_like(layer.weight))

Now on a lot of threads online people suggest that to achieve this one should either directly modify the .data attribute of the parameter or (preferably) use a with torch.no_grad() context manager (see e.g. https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/initialize-nn-linear-with-specific-weights/29005/2 or https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-to-manually-set-the-weights-in-a-two-layer-linear-model/45902/2).
Could anyone explain to me why a context manager is necessary here despite the fact that no gradients are calculated inside it if I do something like
with torch.no_grad():
    layer.weight = torch.nn.Parameter(torch.ones_like(layer.weight))

Any help on this would be much appreciated!
I tried to do some digging in the PyTorch docs to figure this out but didn't get anywhere.
